# CSS Background-Image URL

Tags: html, css, url, background-image

When writing CSS Style for body I encountered a problem and was wondering if anyone can explain the difference.

when I used this

```
 body {
 background-image: url('img/bg.png');
 }
```

it did not work. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

but when I used this

```
 body {
 background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
 }
```

It works fine. I'm quessing it might be because it is in a folder I have to use the '../' but I just wanted to ask to be sure.

Comment: Yep, it has to do with the file location... you can always use an absolute URL to avoid those issues though..

Comment: The ../ at the beginning of the file name takes you up 1 folder from the current folder.  If you just have the slash / at the beginning of the file name it will take you up to the root folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary project structure look like this:

```
index.html
css/
    style.css
img/
    bg.png
```

When you use

```
background-image: url('img/bg.png');
```

that means that location of the image is css/img/bg.png, and when you use

```
background-image: url('../img/bg.png');
```

that means that that location of the image is img/bg.png (`../` - one level higher from current folder, `../../` two levels higher, etc)